# URI for sqlite database file

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-contentprovider

I want to send the database file from an android device to another device by bluetooth.  In order to do that i am using the BluetoothShare.java, and that requires that I provide the URI for the file.

If the database .db file is not included in a content provider. does that mean that I need to enter this file in the content provider so that a URI will be created for it?

if that is not needed then how do I get a URI for the file?

For example all .jpg or .png images are covered by the content provider so they all have a URI,  however if i download to my SD card some random PDF file found on the internet, i am sure that it is not indexed by the content provider, so it does not have a URI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
Uri.fromFile(context.getDatabasePath("databasename.db"));
```